# How do I configure a preseed to continue on a specific error?

Tags: preseed

I have a complex partman configuration that stops on a "partman-auto-lvm/vg_create_error". When I hit "Continue" I get a perfect working installation. How can I ignore this error? Is there any way to pre-script a "Continue" answer? I've tried all of these:

```
d-i partman-auto-lvm/vg_create_error error
partman-base    partman/exception_handler       select
d-i debconf/priority select critical
d-i debconf/frontend select critical
partman-lvm partman-lvm/lvcreate_vgnames  select
d-i partman/exception_handler select Ignore
d-i partman/exception_handler select Continue
partman-base    partman/exception_handler   select  Continue
d-i partman/exception_handler seen false
d-i partman/exception_handler_note seen false
d-i partman/exception_handler unseen
d-i partman/exception_handler_note unseen
d-i partman-auto-lvm/vg_create_error error true
d-i partman/exception_handler select true
d-i debconf/button-continue text false
```

None helped.